Not able to zip to output directory when giving absolute path
I am using 7z.exe on windows command line to zip to an output directory. I understand that -spe switch is used for absolute paths. I am at the moment able to create the zip but not at the specified output directory
The command that I am using is
7z.exe a TRF.zip  -spe c:\Apps\TRF\* -oc:\Apps\TRF\

Can someone tell me what am I missing

I have no idea for this problem through using -o option provided by 7z. But you can try to append filename TRF.zip to full path and forms the following command and this should work:
7z.exe a c:\Apps\TRF\TRF.zip  -spe c:\Apps\TRF\*

